# In javascript, how to detect the position of cursor?

Tags: javascript

[image]

My cursor is here(red flash), I need to detect its position, and locate the beginning "{{?" and the ending"{{?}}" of this expression.

First, how can I find my cursor location?

Comment: Cursor position *where*? What control are you using? Have you consulted the documentation?

Comment: I think there is something like range, selection, caret... In ExtJS.

Answer (score 0):

To get the caret position inside an input field you could use this:

HTML

```
<input type="text" id="input">
```

JS

```
function getCaretPosition(input) {
  var position = 0;
  if (document.selection) { //FOR IE...
    var selrange = document.selection.createRange();
    selrange.moveStart('character', -input.value.length);
    position = selrange.text.length;
  } else if (typeof input.selectionStart !== 'undefined') { //OTHERS
    position = input.selectionStart;
  }
  return position;
}
```

You can call it like this:

```
var position = getCaretPosition(document.getElementById('input'));
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by using range on editable content.
Example:

HTML:

```
<p contenteditable="true">This<!--cursor--> is an editable paragraph.</p>
```

Code:

```
selection = document.getSelection();
range = selection.getRangeAt(0);
startPosition = range.startOffset;
```

output: 4

Comment: And if your content "this is an editable paragraph" is cutted into 3 lines, the cursor is located in the middle, how can I get the 1st line and the last one?

Answer (score 0):

```
<input  type="text"  id="Javascript_example" value="{{? ...}}1{{??}}22{{?}}" onclick="getposition()">
<script>
function getposition(){

var ptr = document.getElementById('Javascript_example');
alert(ptr);

var startPosition = ptr.selectionStart;
alert(startPosition);
var endPosition = ptr.selectionEnd;
alert(endPosition);


}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function foo(event) {
  var x = event.clientX;     // Get the horizontal coordinate
  var y = event.clientY;     // Get the vertical coordinate
  var test = "X coords: " + x + ", Y coords: " + y;
  document.querySelector('.test').innerHTML = test;
}
document.addEventListener('mousemove',foo);
```

```css
.test {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="test"></div>
```

This is how you can do this.
Here is the example made by experts :) >> [0o0o0o0o0o0o0](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_clientx.asp)